# Can we perform this operation on block matrices?

Tags: matrices, intuition, block-matrices

We have a block matrix:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c}
A & 0 & 0 \\
\hline 
0 & B & 0 \\
\hline 
0 & 0 & C
\end{array}\right]
$$

Here $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all permutation matrices *of varying sizes*, raised to a power.  For example, all of the block matrices take on forms such as:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}^a,
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}^b,
\text{ or }
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}^c,
$$

We can suppose that we can only obtain one copy of this matrix.  In other words, we are not allowed to use this block matrix more than once.  **Can we assign corresponding scalars to the matrices $(A \to a, B \to b, C \to c)$ and (using matrix multiplication on the block matrix) get a result $a \cdot b \cdot c$?**

**WHAT I MEAN BY ASSIGNING SCALARS**

Suppose that $A$ is only one of the following:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\text{or}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

...and $B$ is one of the following:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\text{or}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

We could say that the first $A$ matrix is equivalent to $1$, and the second $A$ matrix is equivalent to 2.  Also, the first $B$ equivalent to 3 and the second to 4.  Then if we started with the first $A$ and the second $B$, we would be looking to find a result of $1 \cdot 4$.  If we started with the second $A$ and the second $B$ we would be trying to obtain a result $2 \cdot 4$.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a scalar to a matrix"?

Comment: or by "obtain one copy" of a matrix?

Comment: @Jim:  I've tried to clarify things in the question.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Why not just take diagonal matrices then?  If $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity then $(aI)\cdot(bI)\cdot(cI) = abcI$.

Comment: @Jim: The problem is that I can't always get the block matrices as diagonal matrices.  However, there may be a transformation that transforms the block matrices into diagonal matrices.  That would probably solve the question.  To restate, I can't always start with diagonal matrices, so that is part of the problem.

Comment: Without knowing what matrices you can get there's no way to know.

Comment: @Jim:  The matrices I start with are powers of a permutation matrix.  For example, I start with $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}^a$, or $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}^b$.

Comment: Just giving information piecewise like this isn't going to work.  You need to explain the entire problem otherwise no one can help.

Comment: @Jim:  I've tried to explain the queston better.  Thanks for the help/advice.